# SQL Server - Registering user code to be run when a transaction completion is attempted

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclr, sqltransaction

I have an SQL CLR Stored Procedure which registers an event handler for the completion of the current transaction

```cs
[SqlProcedure]
public static void MySProc()
{
    Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += new TransactionCompletedEventHandler(Current_TransactionCompleted);

    Transaction.Current.Rollback(); //###Current_TransactionCompleted called here###
}

static void Current_TransactionCompleted(object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
{
}
```

And this is the T-SQL calling code

```sql
begin tran
EXEC    [dbo].[MySProc]
commit tran
```

This works as expected: after the call "`Transaction.Current.Rollback()`" the handler gets executed.

However, what I am interested in is to have my handler (or my code anyway) called when the transaction is completed OUTSIDE of "`MySProc()`".

```cs
[SqlProcedure]
public static void MySProc()
{
    Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += new TransactionCompletedEventHandler(Current_TransactionCompleted);
}

static void Current_TransactionCompleted(object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
{
}
```

```sql
begin tran
EXEC    [dbo].[MySProc]
rollback tran -- ###Current_TransactionCompleted NOT called###
```

Is this possible?
If not, is there another way I can hook the current transaction completion and have the "last word" on the transaction outcome (commit or rollback)?

Comment: My guess would be that all the CLR hooks etc only last as long as the CLR call itself and then get forgotten about, and so my guess is that the answer to your question is 'no'. Its an interesting question though.

Comment: Are you doing this as a way of enforcing business logic? e.g. only allow the transaction to complete if x,y,z? ... if so you might be better off with a table trigger that checks things and then throws an error or something like that.

Comment: Imagine this was possible. You would have a lot of fun trying to figure why all transactions are being rolled back, and even more fun trying to stop it from happening without restarting the SQL Server.

Comment: You could try in MySProc to enlist in the existing transaction, and then set up the handler.

Comment: @NielsBerglund If I enlist the handler doesn't get called. The effect is that MSDTC will rollback the main transaction anyway.

Comment: @FrancoTiveron. Ok, well then I do not think it is doable. I'll see if I have some time to "play" around with this.

Answer (score 0):

> what I am interested in is to have my handler called when the transaction is completed OUTSIDE of "`MySProc()`".  ...  Is this possible?

At first I thought that this was not possible at all, but upon further investigation I found that it is (to a degree). In my first test I was printing out a message via `SqlContext.Pipe.Send("...");` when the handler was called. This never displayed anything so I thought that it wasn't being called. However, I had forgotten that there would be no active `SqlContext` within the event handler as it's disconnected from the calling process (i.e. the session that initiated it). Once I switched to using `File.WriteAllText()` in the event handler, then I could see that it was indeed being called upon execution of `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` outside of any SQLCLR code. And, I was using `Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted` just like in the question, and *not* using a static variable as I was also originally testing with. And, there is no need to enlist anything since we are referencing the "current" transaction (i.e. it's already enlisted on the context connection).

HOWEVER, I should clarify that the "this" that works is merely having some SQLCLR code get executed *after* a transaction has either committed or rolled-back. And I even tested by killing a session after beginning a transaction and registering the handler, and it did trigger the event handler.

BUT, there is a slight disconnect between the wording of most of the question and the wording of the title of this question (emphasis added) — Registering user code to be run when a transaction completion **is attempted** — as they seem to indicate different timings of when the handler should run.

> If not, is there another way I can hook the current transaction completion and have the "last word" on the transaction outcome (commit or rollback)?

I would say: Not only "no" (at least not that I'm aware of), but that you wouldn't want it to be "yes" because transactions can be killed for a variety of reasons (deadlocks, session killed, connection pooling executing `sp_reset_connection`, batch-level errors, *any* error if `XACT_ABORT` is `ON`, etc) and you really don't want to interfere with SQL Server's ability to manage transactions.

The closest you can come, as far as I know, is creating SQLCLR methods for "commit" and "rollback" (similar to your example code in the question) and require that your uses only use those SQLCLR stored procedures for doing those actions.

The event handler in SQLCLR runs *after* the `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. This is not an event handler that is trigger by the *request* to end the transaction, but by the transaction actually completing. At that point, there is no way to "have the last word on it".

Comment: "_I don't see how it would be possible.The SQLCLR code is not going to stay running once the method ends and passes control back to the T-SQL context_". Everytime we subscribe to an event the method subscribing goes out of context, yet the event handler method remains in memory ready to be called. On the first execution of MySProc, The method **Current_TransactionCompleted** could be registered as enlisted in the current transaction and remain alive until it is complete.

Comment: _I would say: Not only "no" (at least not that I'm aware of), but that you wouldn't want it to be "yes"_ Yes there are already multiple ways to interfere on transactions, they are call features. I would like to have an additional feature consisting on some user callback code called as part of a transaction commit or rollback statement. I don't see anything strange with this.

Comment: @FrancoTiveron RE: your first comment about about being able to attach to the transaction, you were correct. I updated my answer to reflect the results of new testing. RE: 2nd comment: While you can attach the event handler, it executes _after_ the event. There is no ability to prevent the operation like there is with DML triggers where you can execute a `ROLLBACK` and it will cancel the DML operation. At least I don't see any mechanism to cancel the operation, and the status is either "Committed" or "Aborted", no "Committing" or "Aborting". And no event handler for `TransactionCompleting`.